# Moving blog and maintaining current permalinks

Tags: permalinks, seo, iis

I currently have a blog at http://thinkfuture.com/cfs . Its running WP 3.1 on IIS on a dedicated Windows 2003 server. I have the domain freedombunker.com redirecting to the blog at that URL.

According to my SEO company, I would like to move my blog so that:
1. You can reach the home page if you use http://freedombunker.com
2. The permalinks which pointed to thinkfuture.com/cfs continue to work

For example, a post at this current permalink

http ://thinkfuture.com/cfs/index.php/2011/02/23/obama-welcomes-high-gas-prices/

should remain available as well as at the new permalink

http ://freedombunker.com/index.php/2011/02/23/obama-welcomes-high-gas-prices/

so either permalink can work.

Is this doable? Possible? A pipe dream? Can you run the same blog at two different permalinks with no pain and suffering? Can I just create a new virtual server on the Windows box and point to the wp directory on the first server?

Thanks...Chris

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can definitely run it with the two URLs on the same box. The only reason I've ever seen against doing this is to avoid getting a duplicate content penalty from search engines.

I've never done this on a Windows box, only Linux; however, assuming you can get both URLs to get to the same installation, the rest is platform-agnostic.

Here's how I do this on my sites (when I need to):

```
$url = ( false === strpos( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 'thinkfuture.com' ) ) ? 'http://freedombunker.com' : 'http://thinkfuture.com/cfs';
define('WP_SITEURL', $url);
define('WP_HOME', $url);
```

That will change all dynamic URLs depending on which url was used to get there. Anything that's hardcoded (image sources, etc.) will stay the same, but they should all still work.